# Maximal rectangle algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, rectangles

this is a question concerning a school assignment. 
We had to use an algorithm to find the biggest possible rectangle
with 0s in a matrix with 0's and 1's
I opted for a brute force algorithm as the problem is only a small problem, 
but it doesn't seems to work. Any help/ideas?

```
'Determine greatest rectangle'
def determineBiggest(self):
    best_ll = [0,0]
    best_ur = [-1,-1]
    for llx in range(0,len(self.verkaveling)):
        for lly in range(0,len(self.verkaveling[0])):
            for urx in range(llx, len(self.verkaveling)):
                for ury in range(lly, len(self.verkaveling[0])):
                    if(self.grootte(llx,lly,urx,ury) > self.size(best_ll[0],best_ll[1],best_ur[0],best_ur[1])) and (self.isFree(llx,lly,urx,ury)):
                        best_ll[0]=llx
                        best_ll[1]=lly
                        best_ur[0]=urx
                        best_ur[1]=ury
    print self.size(best_ll[0],best_ll[1],best_ur[0],best_ur[1])                      
'Determine size of rectangle'                       
def grootte(self,a,b,c,d):
    if(a > c) or (b > d):
        return 0
    else:
        return (c-a+1)*(d-b+1)
'Check if rectangle is fully free'
def isFree(self,a,b,c,d):
    for x in range(a, c):
        for y in range(b, d):
            if self.verkaveling[x][y] == "0":
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

Source: [used source](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/the-maximal-rectangle-problem/184410529)

Example:

```
000000
000000
000000
111000
111000
111000
```

This should give 18 and it does.
If I increase this to a 6x10 matrix
and i place a 3x3 submatrix with 1's in 
the lowerleft corner, than that should give me 
42, but only gives me 30

```
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
1110000000
1110000000
1110000000
```

Comment: Offtopic: always use English comments.

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" isn't enough for us to help you. What is actually going wrong? Errors? Incorrect output?

Comment: Incorrect output, I tried fiddling with the size method, but that didn't really work out... Problem comes when there are multiple blocks with a different size that are still free (changing my comments right now)

Comment: You might also want to provide a small sample input.

Comment: Added example and an input with problem

Comment: Be careful with brute force solutions. Is this really "only a small problem"? What happens with a size of 1000x1000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `isFree()` is buggy.  The for loops are never run more than once; you always hit either `return True` or `return False`.

Answer (score 1):

For `isFree`, on the first iteration of the for-loops, it will either return `True` or `False`, it will never get to the second iteration, thus it will only ever check the first cell. (credit to [Armin Rigo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16404527/1711796), just a possible clarification)

So, `return False` needs to be outside the loop.

Also, `True` and `False` should be swapped around (because it **is** free when all `0`s).

**Which rectangle your code is actually returning:**

For the first:

```
111000
111000
111000
```

For the second:

```
1110000000
1110000000
1110000000
```

**So, the code should look something like:** (note - my Python's a bit rusty)

```
def isFree(self,a,b,c,d):
    for x in range(a, c):
        for y in range(b, d):
            if self.verkaveling[x][y] == "1":
                return False
    return True
```